# How to chart only a subset of features in a feature collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, features, chart, feature-collection

I have a feature collection consisting of 44 polygons. I need to chart a time-series of NDVI changes in each of them. I want to chart the polygons in groups of 4 and select them myself, meaning there will be no logic involved other than my personal preference.

The order I would like to give GEE is the following, as an example: "Make a time-series chart of NDVI values *only of IDs 2, 5, 8 and 19* from this feature collection."

Is there a way to filter FCs in this way for charting only, so that I don't need to create various vars?

If helpful, the code for the chart is the basic GEE one as follows:

```
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: ic,
  band: 'NDVI',
  regions: table,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  seriesProperty: 'fid',
})
.setChartType('LineChart')
.setOptions({
  interpolateNulls: true,
  title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
  hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
  },
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    series: {0:{color: 'red'}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter the feature collection. In your case:

```
table.filter(ee.Filter.inList('myProperty', [2, 5, 8, 19]))
```

Where `myProperty` is the property of the features where you keep your ID.